# pandas: sort by the order of appearance

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

Suppose we have a dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.zeros((15,10,)), dtype=int, \
    index=[['a']*5+['b']*5+['c']*5, list(range(15))])
df.index.names=['index0', 'index1']
pd.np.random.seed(0)
for i, v in df.iterrows():
    v.loc[pd.np.random.randint(10)] = 1

df

               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
index0 index1                              
a      0       0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
       1       1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       2       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       3       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       4       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
b      5       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
       6       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       7       0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
       8       0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       9       0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
c      10      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
       11      0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
       12      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
       13      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
       14      0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
```

How to sort first the rows in the blocks a, b and c by the order of appearance of "1" and then sort also a, b and c?

Expected output:

```
               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
index0 index1                              
a      1       1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       2       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       3       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       0       0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
       4       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
c      14      0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       11      0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
       10      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
       12      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
       13      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
b      8       0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       6       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       9       0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
       7       0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
       5       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

Edit: The values can be other than "1", in reality these are different text values.

Comment: Can you add `np.random.seed(0)` at the top to make your input reproducible please? Additionally include the expected output as well.

Comment: Can you include your expected output too?

Comment: @cs95 OK, done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `pandas.DataFrame.groupby` with `idxmax` and `sort_values`:

```
import pandas as pd

l = (d.loc[d.idxmax(1).sort_values().index] for _, d in df.groupby('index0'))
new_df = pd.concat(sorted(l, key= lambda x:list(x.sum()), reverse=True))
print(new_df)
```

Output:

```
               0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
index0 index1                              
a      1       1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       2       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       3       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       0       0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
       4       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
c      14      0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       11      0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0
       10      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0
       12      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
       13      0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1  0
b      8       0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0  0
       6       0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0  0
       9       0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0  0
       7       0  0  0  0  0  1  0  0  0  0
       5       0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  1
```

In case the `1`s are texts and rest is same, try using `pandas.Dataframe.ne`

```
tmp = df.ne(0)
# same operation
new_df = df.loc[new_tmp.index]
```

Comment: I need to sort also the slices a, b and c.

Comment: @MichaelO. My bad. Updated :)

Comment: But what if there are various values, not only "1"? Can you modify this to find not ones, but values different from zero?

Comment: Can you try the last part?